# Linq compare 2 object lists

Tags: c#, linq

I know similar questions already passed this board but I could not find one that answers my question.

I have 2 `list<myObject>` with 3 properties.

The class:

```
    public int MeterID {get; set;}
    public string Datum { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfValues { get; set; }

    public myObject(int meterID, string datum, int numberOfValues)
    {
        this.ID= ID;
        this.Datum = datum;
        this.NumberOfValues = numberOfValues;
    }
```

I want to compare those lists based on the following 2 values `ID, Datum` but I want the result to still be a `List<MyObject>`
So when my object is in listA and listB it should not show up in `newList` after doing the following linq statement

```
var newList = ListA.Select(x => new { x.ID, x.Datum }).Except(ListB.Select(z => new { z.ID, z.Datum }));
```

The statement does not provide me with a MyObject list but with a list with just ID and datum. I also need the NumberOfValues propertie from ListA to be in the newList.

Is there a way to achieve this with linq?

Comment: Why is `Datum` a `String` and not a `DateTime`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
var result = ListA.Where(a => 
                ListB.All(b => b.ID != a.ID || b.Datum != a.Datum)).ToList();
```

This takes all elements from `ListA` for which *all elements in `ListB` are different* (for your definition of different).

If you also want to have the elements of `ListB` which are not in `ListA` you can combine the results:

```
var result = ListA.Where(a => 
                ListB.All(b => b.ID != a.ID || b.Datum != a.Datum)).
                Concat(ListB.Where(b => 
                        ListA.All(a => b.ID != a.ID || b.Datum != a.Datum)).
             ToList();
```

Comment: It looks like this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Curios: Why do you put the point on the end of the line, and not on the second line? (exmpl: ListA.Where(x=>x>y).[newline]FirstOrDefault() instead of ListA.Wjere(x=>x>y)[newline].FirstOrDefault. I think it makes it much clearer compared to your style, that the statement continues

Comment: @Mafii matter of taste, I often have problems formatting code for SO, especially long linq "one-liners".

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [Enumerable.Except()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) with an [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) to exclude the items from `listB`

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int MeterID { get; set; }
    public string Datum { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfValues { get; set; }

    public MyObject(int meterID, string datum, int numberOfValues)
    {
        this.MeterID = meterID;
        this.Datum = datum;
        this.NumberOfValues = numberOfValues;
    }
}

public class MyObjectEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    public override bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return x.MeterID == y.MeterID
            && x.Datum == y.Datum;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.MeterID ^ obj.Datum.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

By encoding the criteria for the comparison in an external object it makes it easier to reuse it elsewhere as well as simplifying changes.

```
[TestClass]
public class CompareListsFixture
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void CompareLists()
    {
        var listA = new List<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject(1,"A", 5), // Matches with 1/A/1
            new MyObject(1,"B", 4),
            new MyObject(2,"A", 3), // Matches with 2/A/4
            new MyObject(2,"C", 2),
        };

        var listB = new List<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject(1,"A", 1),
            new MyObject(2,"A", 4),
            new MyObject(3,"A", 8),
        };

        var expected = new List<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject(1,"B", 4),
            new MyObject(2,"C", 2),
        };

        var actual = listA.Except(listB, new MyObjectEqualityComparer());

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual.ToList(), new MyObjectComparer());

    }

}
```

We use a comparer to comparer the whole object in the `Collection.Assert()`

```
public class MyObjectComparer : Comparer<MyObject>
{
    public override int Compare(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return Format(x).CompareTo(Format(y));
    }

    private static string Format(MyObject obj)
    {
        return $"{obj.MeterID}:{obj.Datum}:{obj.NumberOfValues}";
    }
}
```